# AVPlayer unknown error -12245

Tags: ios, objective-c, video-streaming, avplayer

I am using AVPlayer to stream video content in my universal app. This only occurs if the content is quite a high bit rate meaning the filesize is quite large. When I load the asset by calling:

```
[asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:@[@"tracks"] completionHandler:^{
```

It waits for about 2 minutes and then a popup appears with the error

> The operation could not be completed, An unknown error occurred
>   (-12245)

I have looked furiously for the answer to this but cannot find any examples of the same error.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Is the video file local on the device, or streaming from the web?

Comment: if the video is on a remote server, you can avoid loading an asset asynchronously and simply create an AVPlayerItem like so;  AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:playURL]; and replace the AVPlayerItem with the new one created above like so; [myAVPlayer replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:playerItem];]

Comment: Thanks I will try this. The player is on a remote server so this might work